# south with mysql, yes or no?

Tags: mysql, database, django-models, django-south

Following the south tutorial, The basics, i'm already having problems! This is due to Mysql not supporting migrations i think, but neither MYSQL documentation or South documentation or previous stack overflow questions explicitly state that it cant be done.

My first question therefore is can i force mysql to do migrations?

My 2nd question is would it be easier to learn how to do this or swap the database management system to something else with all that that entails(downloading, learning the new database commands, incorporating into my app, having to re-enter all the database information, etc, etc).

Comment: Migrations are just SQL being generated by South and so don't need to be explicitly supported by MySQL, but you do need to make sure that your database credentials in settings.py are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to first Question: Yes you can!

Second Answer: South is pretty handy, though it has a slight learning curves, you need to fake your previous migrations or even make changes to your migrations file, but that saves lots of pain.